# How to get latitude and longitude from a map in java

Tags: java, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have a java project in which i need to get the latitude and longitude of a place which I specify manually from a map.
I'm actually using this code to get the latitude and longitude using address :

```
public class LongLatService {

    private static final String GEOCODE_REQUEST_URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&";
    private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LongLatService tDirectionService = new LongLatService();
        tDirectionService.getLongitudeLatitude("Rue Delangle, 58210 Varzy, France");
    }

    public void getLongitudeLatitude(String address) {
        try {
            StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(GEOCODE_REQUEST_URL);
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(address)) {
                urlBuilder.append("&address=").append(URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8"));
            }

            final GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(urlBuilder.toString());
            try {
                httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream(), getMethod.getResponseCharSet());

                int data = reader.read();
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                while ((data = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        writer.write(buffer, 0, data);
                }

                String result = writer.toString();
                System.out.println(result.toString());

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader("<"+writer.toString().trim()));
                Document doc = db.parse(is);

                String strLatitude = getXpathValue(doc, "//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat/text()");
                System.out.println("Latitude:" + strLatitude);

                String strLongtitude = getXpathValue(doc,"//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng/text()");
                System.out.println("Longitude:" + strLongtitude);


            } finally {
                getMethod.releaseConnection();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getXpathValue(Document doc, String strXpath) throws XPathExpressionException {
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile(strXpath);
        String resultData = null;
        Object result4 = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result4;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            resultData = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
        }
        return resultData;
    }

}
```

but I want to get the latitude and longitude from a map and use them in other class.

Comment: What do you mean "from a map"? The longitude and latitude of what exactly?

Comment: I mean that I want to have a frame or a web page containing a map and after that I choose a certain place from that map and I want to get that longitude and latitude from my java project

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you using the [Java Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/blob/master/README.md) for this purpose. It is a library developed by Google for Java Developers around the globe in order to use various Google Map features like Geocoding, Direction API, Distance Matrix API etc. In your case you might be using the Geocode API which return the LatLng of the address specified. You need to just integrate this library in your project (Can be used with both Maven And Gradle) and then just a few lines of code would give you the Latitude and Longitude of the address passed through the Google Maps.

Here is the code you need to use for the Geocode API:

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext().setApiKey("AIza...");
GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
    "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043").await();
System.out.println(results[0].formattedAddress);
```

If you do not want to use this library and write your own code you can refer to the code example in [this project](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/ec08ce52854d7e4d568b3fc5c44f1310e82d3640/jdk-1.6-parent/gmap3-parent/gmap3/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/gmap/geocoder/Geocoder.java).

Hope this Helps!!